# Using substring function to parse text

Tags: substring

Using this Substring function in a select statment returns error:

```
Substring([Requirements linked to HZD],1,CHARINDEX('-', [Requirements linked to HZD], 1))
```

error msg:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Substring([Requirements linked to HZD],1,CHARINDEX('-', [Requirements linked to HZD], 1))

String is: URS-89
```

I want to parse out the characters before the - and the characters after the -